# How to convert a video (on disk) to a rtsp stream

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I have a video file on my local disk and i want to create an rtsp stream from it, which i am going to use in one of my project. One way is to create a rtsp stream from vlc but i want to do it with code (python would be better).
I have tried opencv's VideoWritter like this

```
import cv2

_dir = "/path/to/video/file.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(_dir)

framerate = 25.0
out = cv2.VideoWriter(
    "appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc noise-reduction=10000 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=false",
    0,
    framerate,
    (1920, 1080),
)


counter = 0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        out.write(frame)
        print(f"Read {counter} frames",sep='',end="\r",flush=True)
        counter += 1
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
```

But when i stream it on vlc like this

> vlc -v rtsp://127.0.0.1:5000
>   I am getting

```
[00007fbb307a3e18] access_realrtsp access error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5000
[00007fbb2c189f08] core input error: open of `rtsp://127.0.0.1:5000' failed
[00007fbb307a4278] live555 demux error: Failed to connect with rtsp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Gstreamer is another option but as i have never used it, so would be nice if someone points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You tried to expose [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) protocol via TCP server but please note that RTP is not [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) and that RTP (and RTCP) can only be part of RTSP.

Anyways, there is a way to create **RTSP server with GStreamer and Python** by using GStreamer's [GstRtspServer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-rtsp-server/rtsp-server.html?gi-language=python) and Python interface for Gstreamer (`gi` package).

Assuming that you already have Gstreamer on your machine, first [install gi python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213921/python-3-installing-gi-package-with-pip) and then [install Gstreamer RTSP server](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/gir1.2-gst-rtsp-server-1.0) (which is not part of standard Gstreamer installation).

**Python code to expose mp4 container file via simple RTSP server**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GObject, GLib

loop = GLib.MainLoop()
Gst.init(None)

class TestRtspMediaFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory.__init__(self)

    def do_create_element(self, url):
        #set mp4 file path to filesrc's location property
        src_demux = "filesrc location=/path/to/dir/test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux"
        h264_transcode = "demux.video_0"
        #uncomment following line if video transcoding is necessary
        #h264_transcode = "demux.video_0 ! decodebin ! queue ! x264enc"
        pipeline = "{0} {1} ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 config-interval=1 pt=96".format(src_demux, h264_transcode)
        print ("Element created: " + pipeline)
        return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)

class GstreamerRtspServer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rtspServer = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
        factory = TestRtspMediaFactory()
        factory.set_shared(True)
        mountPoints = self.rtspServer.get_mount_points()
        mountPoints.add_factory("/stream1", factory)
        self.rtspServer.attach(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = GstreamerRtspServer()
    loop.run()
```

Note that

- this code will expose RTSP stream named `stream1` on default port 8554
- I used `qtdemux` to get video from MP4 container. You could extend above pipeline to extract audio too (and expose it too via RTSP server)
- to decrease CPU processing you can only extract video without decoding it and encoding it again to H264. However, if transcoding is needed, I left one commented line that will do the job (but it might choke less powerful CPUs).

You can play this with VLC

```
vlc -v rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream1
```

or with Gstreamer

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream1
```

However, **If you actually do not need RTSP but just end-to-end RTP** following Gstreamer pipeline (that utilizes [rtpbin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtpbin.html)) will do the job

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin \ 
filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux \
demux.video_0 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=true async=false
```

and VLC can play it with

```
vlc -v rtp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Comment: Thank you so the solution, it worked but only for video with codec: H.264 (Main Profile). Is there a way i can make video with codec H.265 (Main Profile) rtsp streams with the same code? @Dusan Kovacevic

Comment: @shahidammer maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547276/how-to-stream-in-h265-using-gstreamer) SO Q/A can help you with H.265. In that case in example above you would need to uncomment transcoding part and add h265 encoder element.

Comment: Nevermind, it did work with I uncomment the line you menioned. Thank you. 
However, the quality drops when i view it in vlc. Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: I assume that quality drops because software transcoding eats a lot of CPU power. Once I used hardware transcoding that utilizes GPU and it produced much much better performance. But that was on specific platform... and that is another story :)

Comment: Is there a way i can move to GPU from CPU too?

Comment: [This](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/vaapi/index.html?gi-language=python) could be starting point for your research.

Comment: Thanks for the code. New to GST. How to convert this code to continuously stream the same video in loops?

Answer (score 0):

**How to add the framerate and bitrate in pipeline**

```
def do_create_element(self, url):
    #set mp4 file path to filesrc's location property
    src_demux = "filesrc location=/path/to/dir/test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux"
    h264_transcode = "demux.video_0"
    #uncomment following line if video transcoding is necessary
    #h264_transcode = "demux.video_0 ! decodebin ! queue ! x264enc"
    pipeline = "{0} {1} ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 config-interval=1 pt=96".format(src_demux, h264_transcode)
    print ("Element created: " + pipeline)
    return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).